# Find the x-coordinate of a tangent to a curve when it meets the curve again

Tags: curves, tangent-line

Working through a pure maths text book - as my hobby is - I found the following question:

Find the equation of the tangent to the curve $y=\frac{5}{12}x^3-\frac{13}{9}x$ at the point P at which $x = x_0$. Show that the x-coordinate of the point Q where this tangent meets the curve again is $-2x_0$ and find the values of $x_0$ for which the tangent at P is the normal at Q.

I worked out the first part OK. I found the tangent to be $y=(\frac{5}{4}x_0^2-\frac{13}{9})x - \frac{5}{6}(x_0^3)$

I thought for the second part I need to solve this equation:

$(\frac{5}{4}x_0^2-\frac{13}{9})x - \frac{5}{6}(x_0^3)=\frac{5}{12}x-\frac{13}{9}x$

But I cannot solve it to get the answer in the text book, which is $\pm\frac{1}{3}\sqrt5,\pm\frac{2}{3}\sqrt2$

My workings took me to:

$x=\frac{45x^3-156x+90x_0^3}{135x_0^2-156}$

but this seems a dead end.

Comment: I am not sure the solution you mentioned for the first part is right. Can you please check it again?

Comment: Specifically, why does it pass through the given point?

Comment: The curve is not a conic section so the tags need editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first part of the solution is correct. For the second part, you need to equate $y$ value of the curve and the tangent line.

$ \displaystyle \left(\frac{5}{4}x_0^2-\frac{13}{9}\right)x - \frac{5}{6}x_0^3=\frac{5}{12}x^3 -\frac{13}{9}x$

$ \displaystyle \frac{5}{4}x_0^2 \ x - \frac{5}{6}x_0^3=\frac{5}{12}x^3$

$ \displaystyle 3 x_0^2 \ x - 2 x_0^3 = x^3$

$x^3 - 3 x_0^2 \ x + 2 x_0^3 = 0$

$(x- x_0)^2 (x + 2x_0) = 0$

and hence $x = - 2 x_0$ is the x-value of intersection point $Q$.

Now for the third part, find slope of the tangent at $Q$, just like you did for first part.

Product of the slopes of tangents at $P$ and $Q$ should be $-1$ as the tangent at $P$ is normal to the curve at $Q$. Find at what value of $x_0$, that happens.

Comment: Thank you.  I would not have been able to make the step from $x^3 - 3 x_0^2 \ x + 2 x_0^3 = 0$ to $(x- x_0)^2 (x + 2x_0) = 0$. It's obvious now you have done it but how does one see the connection in the first place? Or it just practice or intuition? or is there some rule? I thought of the factor theorem but $x$ and $x_0$ are different from each other.

Comment: @Steblo A bit of cheating helps here. It is a cubic equation. As the line is tangent to the curve at $x = x_0$, I know $(x - x_0)$ will be a root. Also the question asks to show $x = - 2x_0$ is the intersection point. So I already know $(x + 2 x_0)$ will also be a root.

Comment: Also an additional point, when you solve such equations, the point of tangency will be a double root. That is why $(x - x_0)^2$. But even if you just knew that we should look for roots $(x - x_0)$ and $(x + 2 x_0)$, that would work.